# ORDER BY sequelize nodeJS

Tags: node.js, include, sequelize.js, sql-order-by

I want to get my user ordered by 'game_order'. I try a lot of possibilities but with no success (everytime the result is according to the id of user). I'm using the sequelize version: 5.21.12

This is my request:

```
exports.get_user_in_game = function(req, res) {
  models.user.findAll({
    attributes: ['id','username'],
    include: [
    {
      model: models.user_game,
      attributes: ['game_id','user_id','game_order','turn_to_pick'],
      where :{
        game_id : req.body.game_id
      },
      order:[
        /*[{model: models.user_game},'game_order','ASC']*/
        /*[models.user_game,'game_order','ASC']*/
        /*'game_order','ASC'*/
        ['game_order','ASC']
      ]
    }
    ]
  }).then(function(user_list) {
    res.status(200).send(user_list);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).end();
  });
};
```

What is the good way to order in a include model with sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.

```
exports.get_user_in_game = function(req, res) {
  models.user.findAll({
    attributes: ['id','username'],
    include: [
    {
      model: models.user_game,
      attributes: ['game_id','user_id','game_order','turn_to_pick'],
      where :{
        game_id : req.body.game_id
      },
    }
    ],
    order:[
        [models.user_game,'game_order','ASC'],
      ]
  }).then(function(user_list) {
    res.status(200).send(user_list);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).end();
  });
};
```

For more nested includes have look on this [issue on github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553).

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I already tried that (second try) and it doesn't work ...

Comment: Oh! I couldn't notice. You need to take out order clause from your include. I 've updated check now.